# Execute Compound SQL using Liquibase / DB2

Tags: plsql, db2, liquibase

I'm trying to execute the following code with Liquibase.

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE I INT DEFAULT 6;
WHILE I <= 10 DO
    INSERT INTO LQBTEST.department (id,name,active) VALUES (I,"pl",1);
    SET I = I + 1;
END WHILE;
END@
```

I tried it with

```
<sql endDelimiter="@" splitStatements="false"></sql>
```

which resulted in liquibase telling me that my markup was wrong
then I tried:

```
<sqlFile endDelimiter="@"
        path="proc.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        splitStatements="false"
        stripComments="true"/>
```

results in:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorExc
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=pl, DRIVER=3.63.75
```

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: `"pl"` is a column name, not a string. `'pl'` would be string. Btw: that's not PL/SQL. There is no `BEGIN ATOMIC` or `SET  in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [DB2 Information Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00206n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-0-132), the error you are getting, `-206`, means "*name* is not valid in the context where it is used."

In this case, `name` corresponds to the `SQLERRMC` field in the error you are getting, which is `pl`. As @a_horse_with_no_name said, double-quoted strings are identifiers, not string literals, which is likely why you are getting the error.

Comment: Additionally to that, I had to remove the attribute splitStatements="false"